# Music Player with delayed playback function for dance

Tags: windows, audio, music, media-player

I'm looking for a music player software for Windows where I can configure a **delay** between **clicking on the playback button** and the **actual playback**.

I need this for dance training at home, because I need a few seconds to move from my computer to the initial dance position.

The only "solution" I found until now is to embed the audio file in Powerpoint and configure a delay in the animations tab... but I have to do this with every file separately...

Answer (score 1):

I have written a VLC extension for you.

**Steps:**

1. If you do not have [VLC Media player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html) installed, Download and install it.
2. Download the extension from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_x1XHnzpYiWTmFSajBYYkNZSW8/view?usp=sharing).
3. Move the downloaded file to *INSTALL_DIR\VLC\lua\extensions*
4. Open VLC Media player.
5. If you have followed the above steps correctly then you should see extention as `Delayer` under the `view` menu.

[image]

6. Open the media file that you wish to play. VLC will start playing the file automatically. Stop the playback.
7. Open the extension by clicking on `Delayer` **(1)**
8. Type the amount of delay that want in the text box. **(2)**

[image]

Clicking on <kbd>Delayed start</kbd> will start the playback after the time specified in the text box.

<kbd>Play</kbd> and <kbd>Pause</kbd>.. well play and pause the playback.

***Note:*** This has been only tested on Windows. I am not sure how the plugin would behave in Linux. If you want me to change the plugin behavior in anyway please do comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to have a delay of fixed length with almost any media player that supports playlist why not find, or record, an audio file with on click per second - *I would suggest 5 or 10 seconds* and add it, possibly more than once, to a playlist ahead of the item you wish to dance to.

You could also consider one with a few seconds pause - you probably need about the same time to move to your start position each time - and then 3 or 5 clicks or taps just before the end.

This ties in with the practice that many bands can be seen doing where the drummer will click his/her sticks together as a countdown to start.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the free replayer application from https://replayer.app

While it does not explicitly support a pause before a track, it allows to start at predefined positions repeatedly, and it features a "preplay" duration that lets the playing start some time before the requested position.

I am the author of said replayer.